# Basic scattering with Geometry Nodes on Blender 3.0

Tags: geometry-nodes

I was using geometry nodes on version `2.93.5` for having more control over scattering. One of the essential nodes for that was `attribute randomize`. Now Blender 3.0 is out but apparent instance and randomize nodes removed. My question is how can I achieve basic scattering over face geometry with geometry nodes?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A similar node chain might be

1.Distribute Points on Faces
2.Random Value
3.Instance on Points

Instance on points will take rotation and scale values.

Here the node named "rocks" is a Collection Info node.

[image]